# I'm lost with a Google Sheets function

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column named "Trip", in which I have infos such as the hotel, country, and type of trip.
The thing is these infos are hand typed, so sometimes instead of typing "HOTEL ABC", the person entering the infos simply enters "ABC", or event "HTL ABC".
Also, ABC can also refer to a country.

What I want is to extract all hotel names on each cell. Here's the function I created, but I can't get it to work. (Y2 is the TRIP Column)

```html
=IFS(AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "ZAHIR");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "LODGE"));"ZAHIR LODGE"; AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "ZAHIR");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "ILE"));"ZAHIR DE L'ILE";AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "ARC");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "CIEL"));"ARC EN CIEL";REGEXMATCH(Y2; "NOSY"); "NOSY BE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ANTOREM");"ANTOREMBA LODGE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"VANILLE"); "JARDIN VANILLE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SAKAT");"SAKATIA LODGE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SAUVAGE");"NATURE SAUVAGE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ANDILA");"ANDILANA"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"AMARI"); "AMARINA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"NOIR") "CORAIL NOIR"; REGEXMATCH(Y2; "LOHA") "LOHARANO" ;REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ROYAL");"ROYAL BEACH";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"VANILA"); "VANILA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"HEUR");"HEURE BLEUE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RAVI"); "RAVINTSARA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RESIDENCE"); "THE RESIDENCE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KOMBA LODGE"); "TSARA KOMBA LODGE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO REEF"); "PALUMBO REEF"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO KENDWA"); "PALUMBO KENDWA";AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "BLUE");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "MARLIN"));"BLUEMARLIN";AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "MY");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "BLU"));"MY BLUE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MVUVI"); "MVUVI";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO REEF"); "PALUMBO REEF";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RAFU"); "KARAFUU";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PARADI"); "NEXT PARADISE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KINASI"); "KINASI"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALACE");"RIU PALACE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MANTA"); "MANTA RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ZURI"); "ZURI RESORT";AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2; "EDEN");REGEXMATCH(Y2; "KENDWA"));"EDEN KENDWA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KIWENGWA"); "KIWENGWA BEACH RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PAJE"); "PAJE PALMS BEACH RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2; "SUNSHINE"); "SUNSHINE MARINE LODGE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"HAKUNA"); "HAKUNA MAJIWE BEACH RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MAJIWE"); "HAKUNA MAJIWE BEACH RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"BAOBAB"); "BAOBAB BEACH RESORT";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"JACAR"); "JACARANDA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"GARODA"); "GARODA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MAWE"); "MAWE";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"TWIGA"); "TWIGA";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RACUDA"); "BARRACUDA INN";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ACQUA"); "ACQUARIUS";REGEXMATCH(Y2;"WATAM"); "EDEN WATAMU BEACH"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"LONNO"); "LONNO LODGE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ALAWI"); "ALAWI BOUTIQUE RESORT"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KOBE"); "KOBE RESORT"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SUN PALM"); "SUN PALM RESORT"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"CAROL"); "VILLAS CAROLINE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"CORAL"); "CORAL AZUR"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RADISSON"); "RADISSON BLUPOSTE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RECIF"); "RECIF ATTITUDE"; REGEXMATCH(Y2;"FRIDAY"); "FRIDAY ATTITUDE";)
```

I've been working on this table for 2 days now and just can't find the answer.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a dummy worksheet so we can visualize what you are trying to attain with your formula.

Comment: Please share a copy of your sheet with your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are missing semicolons before "CORAIL NOIR" and "LOHARANO" .
2. You need to remove the final semicolon after "FRIDAY ATTITUDE" because `IFS expects all arguments after position 0 to be in pairs` and the final semicolon makes Google Sheets think another set of arguments is coming.
3. You can help yourself out with future troubleshooting by spacing out your function better - eg the following will still work when pasted into Google Sheets:

```
=IFS(
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ZAHIR");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"LODGE"));"ZAHIR LODGE";
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ZAHIR");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ILE"));"ZAHIR DE L'ILE";
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ARC");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"CIEL"));"ARC EN CIEL";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"NOSY"); "NOSY BE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ANTOREM");"ANTOREMBA LODGE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"VANILLE"); "JARDIN VANILLE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SAKAT"); "SAKATIA LODGE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SAUVAGE"); "NATURE SAUVAGE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ANDILA"); "ANDILANA"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"AMARI"); "AMARINA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"NOIR"); "CORAIL NOIR"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"LOHA"); "LOHARANO";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ROYAL");"ROYAL BEACH";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"VANILA"); "VANILA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"HEUR"); "HEURE BLEUE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RAVI"); "RAVINTSARA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RESIDENCE"); "THE RESIDENCE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KOMBA LODGE"); "TSARA KOMBA LODGE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO REEF"); "PALUMBO REEF"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO KENDWA"); "PALUMBO KENDWA";
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"BLUE");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MARLIN")); "BLUEMARLIN";
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MY");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"BLU")); "MY BLUE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MVUVI"); "MVUVI";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALUMBO REEF"); "PALUMBO REEF";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RAFU"); "KARAFUU";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PARADI"); "NEXT PARADISE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KINASI"); "KINASI"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PALACE"); "RIU PALACE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MANTA"); "MANTA RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ZURI"); "ZURI RESORT";
AND(REGEXMATCH(Y2;"EDEN");REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KENDWA")); "EDEN KENDWA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KIWENGWA"); "KIWENGWA BEACH RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"PAJE"); "PAJE PALMS BEACH RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SUNSHINE"); "SUNSHINE MARINE LODGE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"HAKUNA"); "HAKUNA MAJIWE BEACH RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MAJIWE"); "HAKUNA MAJIWE BEACH RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"BAOBAB"); "BAOBAB BEACH RESORT";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"JACAR"); "JACARANDA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"GARODA"); "GARODA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"MAWE"); "MAWE";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"TWIGA"); "TWIGA";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RACUDA"); "BARRACUDA INN";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ACQUA"); "ACQUARIUS";
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"WATAM"); "EDEN WATAMU BEACH"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"LONNO"); "LONNO LODGE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"ALAWI"); "ALAWI BOUTIQUE RESORT"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"KOBE"); "KOBE RESORT"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"SUN PALM"); "SUN PALM RESORT"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"CAROL"); "VILLAS CAROLINE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"CORAL"); "CORAL AZUR"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RADISSON"); "RADISSON BLUPOSTE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"RECIF"); "RECIF ATTITUDE"; 
REGEXMATCH(Y2;"FRIDAY"); "FRIDAY ATTITUDE"
)
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm. Never thought of formatting the functions like this, it helps a lot. Thanks again!

Comment: Another question though: how can I make it so when a cell matches with two values those two values are displayed in 2 cells? 
For example A1 matches with Palace and Manta, and I would like to have RIU PALACE and MANTA RESORT in two separated cells.

Comment: That's going to be difficult to do within a function like this - `IFS` returns a value that corresponds to the *first* true condition, so it can only return one match. You could reverse the order of all the conditions in a second function, but this will only help for a second match (can't match three) and it will return duplicates. You might want to explore Google Apps Script which gives you more flexibility in the functions and code that you can run - could loop through all conditions and return all matches this way.